# What does "MSL" (shift in ones) in arm64 assembly stand for?

Tags: assembly, bit-shift, arm64, mnemonics

In an assembler instruction like

```
movi    v30.2S, #0x3c, msl #0x8
```

msl will cause that the value `0x3cff` (value is shifted left and ones are inserted at the bottom) is moved to the target but what does MSL stand for? For example LSL stands for "Logical Shift Left".

Comment: Magical Shift Left... though, it might have just been "modified" shift left.

Comment: `lsl` is left shift with zero-fill of low order bits, while 'msl' is left shift with one-fill of low order bits. So "modified shift left" sounds reasonable, but I have yet to find it spelled out in official ARM documentation.

Comment: On other CPUs, for example on m68k, the two kinds of shifts are Logical and Arithmetic.  Perhaps M is mathematic(al)?

Comment: @chexum: That sounds implausible to me, given what it does.  Normal left shift (shifting in zeros) multiplies by 2 for signed or unsigned numbers.  Some ISAs, like x86, have mnemonic synonyms for arithmetic and logical left shift, but they use the same machine code because it's the same operation.   ARM does have logical and arithmetic *right* shifts.  But this MSL is *not* a simple mathematical operation.  It's multiplying by a power of 2 and adding one less than that power of 2.  i.e. `x * 2^n + (2^n-1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but based on [the capstone documentation](https://docs.rs/capstone/0.6.0/src/capstone/arch/arm64.rs.html), it may stand for "Masking shift lift".

Only thing I question about it is that it says `lsl` may stand for "`Logical shift lift`", and not "`Logical shift left`", so maybe "`Masking shift left`"?

[image: screenshot in case it goes down]

Comment: [This blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20150327020657/http://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2014/12/16/a64-shift-and-extend-operations-operand-modifiers) written by an ARM employee confirms that name.